# Wrong argument cast in pthread_create

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

what I'm trying to do is send the integer value 0 to the function to use it as an index of my array. But instead of writing to patients[0], it writes to patients[1]. Any idea why?
I am simple looping from 0 to 1, just to see if it's passing the value 0 correctly, passing i(0) to function, assign myArr[0] to something, but it assigns to myArr[1] instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct patient_info {
    pthread_t thread;
    char treatment;
    char department[20];
} patient;

patient patients[1000];

void* registration(void* arg)
{
    int p_num = *((int*)arg); // my array index that supposed to be 0

        if (rand() % 2 == 0)
        {
            patients[p_num].treatment = 'M';
        }
        else
        {
            patients[p_num].treatment = 'S';
        }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1; i++) // simple for loop to create my thread
    {
        if (pthread_create(&patients[i].thread, NULL, &registration, (void*)&i) != 0)
        {
            perror("There has been an error with pthread_create().");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for (size_t j = 0; j < 1; j++)
    {
        if (pthread_join(patients[j].thread, NULL) != 0)
        {
            perror("There has been an error with the pthread_join().");
            return 2;
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; i++) // make this loop to see where it is writing.
    {
        if (patients[i].treatment == 'M' || patients[i].treatment == 'S')
        {    
            printf("Treatment is: %c %d\n", patients[i].treatment, i);
        }        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: all your threads are getting a pointer to _the same int_.

Comment: @Mat But am I not only use 1 thread right now? Because I'm looping only for once.

Comment: But when does your loop stop looping? What is the value of `i` then?

Comment: @covenant You pass the address of `i` to each thread you create - the same address to the same variable `i`.  The value of `i` changes as the threads are getting created...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a *pointer* to `i`, so each thread points to the *same* `i` variable.

Thus, the threads *race* to get *their* value. (e.g.) threadA wants `0` and threadB wants `1`. But, if the main task is fast enough *both* might see either 0 *or* 1. Thus, a conflict.

Also, in `main`, `i` is a `size_t` but in `registration`, it's an `int` pointer. They are [probably] different sizes.

The solution is to pass `i` by *value*

```
pthread_create(&patients[i].thread, NULL, &registration, (void *) i)
```

And, in `registration`, we accept by value:

```
void *
registration(void *arg)
{
    size_t p_num = (size_t) arg;

    // ...

    return (void *) 0;
}
```

Here's the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct patient_info {
    pthread_t thread;
    char treatment;
    char department[20];
} patient;

patient patients[1000];

void *
registration(void *arg)
{
    // my array index that supposed to be 0
// NOTE/BUG: this uses the wrong size pointer and to prevent the race condition
// we want to accept by value
#if 0
    int p_num = *((int *) arg);
#else
    size_t p_num = (size_t) arg;
#endif

    if (rand() % 2 == 0) {
        patients[p_num].treatment = 'M';
    }
    else {
        patients[p_num].treatment = 'S';
    }

    return NULL;
}

int
main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    // simple for loop to create my thread
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        if (pthread_create(&patients[i].thread, NULL, &registration,
#if 0
            (void *) &i) != 0) {
#else
            (void *) i) != 0) {
#endif
            perror("There has been an error with pthread_create().");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for (size_t j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        if (pthread_join(patients[j].thread, NULL) != 0) {
            perror("There has been an error with the pthread_join().");
            return 2;
        }
    }

    // make this loop to see where it is writing.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (patients[i].treatment == 'M' || patients[i].treatment == 'S') {
            printf("Treatment is: %c %d\n", patients[i].treatment, i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Since you've gone to the trouble of creating a patient `struct`, we can clean up the code a bit by using and passing around some pointers to that `struct`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct patient_info {
    pthread_t thread;
    char treatment;
    char department[20];
} patient;

patient patients[1000];

void *
registration(void *arg)
{
    patient *pt = arg;

    if (rand() % 2 == 0) {
        pt->treatment = 'M';
    }
    else {
        pt->treatment = 'S';
    }

    return NULL;
}

int
main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    patient *pt;

    // simple for loop to create my thread
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        pt = &patients[i];

        if (pthread_create(&pt->thread, NULL, &registration, pt) != 0) {
            perror("There has been an error with pthread_create().");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for (size_t j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        pt = &patients[j];

        if (pthread_join(pt->thread, NULL) != 0) {
            perror("There has been an error with the pthread_join().");
            return 2;
        }
    }

    // make this loop to see where it is writing.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        pt = &patients[i];

        if (pt->treatment == 'M' || pt->treatment == 'S') {
            printf("Treatment is: %c %d\n", pt->treatment, i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Note that we define the patient array to have 1000 elements.

At present, we are only creating *one* thread.

Presumably, we want to process all 1000 records.

But, creating 1000 *threads* is problematic and doesn't scale too well. If we had 100,000 patients, we [probably] could *not* create 100,000 threads in parallel.

And, even if we could, the system would spend most of its time switching between threads and the system would slow to a crawl.

Better to have a "pool" of "worker" threads and feed them a few records at a time.

If we do that, there's no reason to put the `pthread_t` into the patient record. We can have *two* separate arrays: one for patients and another [smaller] array for "active" threads.

There are many ways to do this. Ideally, we monitor thread completion and add new threads dynamically. But, that's a bit complicated for a first try.

Here's a version that splits things up into limited chunks. It's the "good enough for now" solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct patient_info {
    char treatment;
    char department[20];
} patient;

#define NPATIENT    1000
patient patients[NPATIENT];

#define NWORKER     10
pthread_t threads[NWORKER];

void *
registration(void *arg)
{
    patient *pt = arg;

    if (rand() % 2 == 0) {
        pt->treatment = 'M';
    }
    else {
        pt->treatment = 'S';
    }

    return NULL;
}

int
main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    patient *pt;

    for (size_t patlo = 0;  patlo < NPATIENT;  patlo += NWORKER) {
        size_t pathi = patlo + NWORKER;

        if (pathi > NPATIENT)
            pathi = NPATIENT;

        size_t itsk;

        // simple for loop to create my thread
        itsk = 0;
        for (size_t ipat = patlo; ipat < pathi; ipat++, itsk++) {
            pt = &patients[ipat];

            if (pthread_create(&threads[itsk], NULL, &registration, pt) != 0) {
                perror("There has been an error with pthread_create().");
                return 1;
            }
        }

        // join this chunk of threads
        itsk = 0;
        for (size_t ipat = patlo; ipat < pathi; ipat++, itsk++) {
            pt = &patients[ipat];

            if (pthread_join(threads[itsk], NULL) != 0) {
                perror("There has been an error with the pthread_join().");
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }

    // make this loop to see where it is writing.
    for (size_t ipat = 0; ipat < NPATIENT; ipat++) {
        pt = &patients[ipat];

        if (pt->treatment == 'M' || pt->treatment == 'S') {
            printf("Treatment is: %c %zu\n", pt->treatment, ipat);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> But why is it necessary to use pointer to struct in the below example you gave?

It's *not* strictly necessary, but it's a cleaner more extensible option. And, without optimization by the compiler, it generates *faster* code.

Doing `pt->whatever` is simpler than `patients[i].whatever` everywhere.

> And how can 2 thread race for 0 or 1 when I only loop for once (create only 1 thread)? –
> covenant

With just one thread, they don't race. But, if we switched to a larger number (e.g.) 2, they *would* race.

Remember, we fixed *two* problems:

1. The race condition
2. The size mismatch between `i` in `main`, where it was `size_t` which is 8 bytes and `p_num` in the thread function where the size was 4.

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> Thank you so much again. Can you please expend the names of patlo, pathi, ipat and itsk?

Well, `itsk` is the easiest. If I didn't know this code and had to analyze it, I would look at all the places it was used. It is only used as an *index* into the `threads` array.

"tsk" is a "signature" style for me (Think: "task"). I often use three char abbreviations/acronyms. The `threads` array is just a `pthread_t`. But, if we needed more per-task (i.e. per-thread) information, I'd create a per-task struct (e.g.):

```
typedef struct {
    pthread_t tsk_pthr;                 // the thread ID
    int tsk_patdone;                    // number of patients processed
    long long tsk_elap;                 // elapsed time of task
} tsk_t;
```

And, the pointer to the struct would be (e.g.): `tsk_t *tskcur;`

As to `ipat`, it is the *index* into the `parents` array. When we split up the parents arrays into chunks of `NWORKER`, then `patlo` is the first index of the current chunk and `pathi` is the index that is one *beyond* the end of the current chunk. So, with `NWORKER` at 10, then `patlo,pathi` would be: `0,10 10,20 20,30` ...

> And yes, what I want was working with 1000 threads at once, but as you said above it is problematic and I have 4 CPU only. Is it a better idea to change NWORKER to 4? –
> covenant

Generally, using the number of CPUs is a good starting point. I've had luck with up to 2x the number of CPUs. This is a tuning parameter. You have to try it, measure it, adjust it. The "best" number can depend on the type of work being done.

> Can this be done by semaphores or mutex_locks? Let's say I can only let 10 thread inside of my registration function. –
> covenant

A more advanced implementation (vs. the "good enough for now" implementation that I did above) would start NWORKER threads at the start. Then would just feed new work to the various threads. Then threads would only be joined at the end [i.e. *not* after each chunk].

To get this more dynamic, semaphores could help. *If* one is careful--otherwise, they "serialize" waiting on the semaphores. Logically correct, but parallelism is reduced.

Or, condition variables might help (e.g.) `pthread_cond_signal` et. al.

Or, we could use *atomic* operations (from `stdatomic.h`). Each thread runs independently and "atomically" grabs the "next" index into the patient array. For the simple use case here, this is [probably] the most performant.

Here is a version that does that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

typedef struct patient_info {
    char treatment;
    char department[20];
} patient;

#define NPATIENT    1000
patient patients[NPATIENT];

size_t patidx = 0;

#define NWORKER     10
pthread_t threads[NWORKER];

void *
registration(void *arg)
{
    size_t ipat;
    patient *pt;

    while (1) {
        // _atomically_ grab the next index to use
        // NOTE: these next two lines are functionally equivalent, but ...
#if 0
        // ordinary code -- has race condition
        ipat = patidx++;
#else
        // atomic code -- works correctly
        ipat = atomic_fetch_add(&patidx,1);
#endif

        // stop if we are done
        if (ipat >= NPATIENT)
            break;

        pt = &patients[ipat];

        if (rand() % 2 == 0) {
            pt->treatment = 'M';
        }
        else {
            pt->treatment = 'S';
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

int
main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    patient *pt;

    // start all threads
    for (size_t itsk = 0;  itsk < NWORKER;  ++itsk) {
        if (pthread_create(&threads[itsk], NULL, &registration, (void *) itsk)
            != 0) {
            perror("There has been an error with pthread_create().");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // wait for all threads to complete
    for (size_t itsk = 0;  itsk < NWORKER;  ++itsk) {
        pthread_join(threads[itsk], NULL);
    }

    // make this loop to see where it is writing.
    for (size_t ipat = 0; ipat < NPATIENT; ipat++) {
        pt = &patients[ipat];

        if (pt->treatment == 'M' || pt->treatment == 'S') {
            printf("Treatment is: %c %zu\n", pt->treatment, ipat);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #3:**

In the above code examples, I missed the fact that `rand` is *not* thread safe and that `rand_r` should be used instead.

Also, I [briefly] talked about performance and how it should be measured in order to tune the app.

So, I've created [hopefully final :-)] version that incorporates the orignal chunked ("good enough for now") version with the "atomic" version, the use of the `tsk_t` struct, additional use pointers, macros, and performance measurement.

I had to move everything to subfunctions. This is good example of something that good programmers have to do.

Anyway, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

unsigned int seed;                      // random seed

typedef struct patient_info {
    char treatment;
    char department[20];
} patient;

#ifndef NPATIENT
#define NPATIENT    100000
#endif
int npatient = 1000;
patient patients[NPATIENT];

size_t patidx;                          // current patient index

typedef struct {
    int tsk_active;                     // 1=task active/joinable
    pthread_t tsk_pthr;                 // the thread ID
    unsigned int tsk_seed;              // random seed
    patient *tsk_pat;                   // pointer to patient record
    void *tsk_ret;                      // thread return value
} tsk_t;

#ifndef NWORKER
#define NWORKER     100
#endif
int nworker;

tsk_t threads[NWORKER];

#define TSKFORCUR(_tsk) \
    tsk_t *_tsk = &threads[0];  tsk < &threads[nworker];  ++tsk
#define TSKFORALL(_tsk) \
    tsk_t *_tsk = &threads[0];  tsk < &threads[NWORKER];  ++tsk

typedef struct {
    int (*fnc_ptr)(void);               // pointer to function
    const char *fnc_who;                // name of function
    double fnc_tscbest;                 // best time
    int fnc_nworker;                    // best number of workers
} fnc_t;

int
joinall(void)
{

    for (TSKFORCUR(tsk)) {
        if (! tsk->tsk_active)
            continue;

        if (pthread_join(tsk->tsk_pthr, &tsk->tsk_ret) != 0) {
            perror("There has been an error with the pthread_join().");
            return 2;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

// registration_chunked -- "chunked" thread function
void *
registration_chunked(void *arg)
{
    tsk_t *tsk = arg;
    patient *pt = tsk->tsk_pat;

    if (rand_r(&tsk->tsk_seed) % 2 == 0)
        pt->treatment = 'M';
    else
        pt->treatment = 'S';

    return NULL;
}

// perform_chunked -- do separate create/join on threads
int
perform_chunked(void)
{
    int code = 0;

    for (size_t patlo = 0;  patlo < npatient;  patlo += nworker) {
        for (TSKFORALL(tsk))
            tsk->tsk_active = 0;

        size_t pathi = patlo + nworker;
        if (pathi > npatient)
            pathi = npatient;

        // simple for loop to create my thread
        tsk_t *tsk = &threads[0];
        for (size_t ipat = patlo;  ipat < pathi;  ++ipat, ++tsk) {
            tsk->tsk_active = 1;

            tsk->tsk_pat = &patients[ipat];

            if (pthread_create(&tsk->tsk_pthr, NULL, registration_chunked,
                tsk) != 0) {
                perror("There has been an error with pthread_create().");
                return 1;
            }
        }

        // join this chunk of threads
        code = joinall();
        if (code)
            break;
    }

    return code;
}

// registration_atomic -- atomic thread function
void *
registration_atomic(void *arg)
{
    tsk_t *tsk = arg;
    size_t ipat;
    patient *pt;

    while (1) {
        // _atomically_ grab the next index to use
        // NOTE: these next two lines are functionally equivalent, but ...
#if 0
        // ordinary code -- has race condition
        ipat = patidx++;
#else
        // atomic code -- works correctly
        ipat = atomic_fetch_add(&patidx,1);
#endif

        // stop if we are done
        if (ipat >= npatient)
            break;

        pt = &patients[ipat];

        if (rand_r(&tsk->tsk_seed) % 2 == 0) {
            pt->treatment = 'M';
        }
        else {
            pt->treatment = 'S';
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

// perform_atomic -- do all work with atomic primitives
int
perform_atomic(void)
{

    atomic_store(&patidx,0);

    // start all threads
    for (TSKFORCUR(tsk)) {
        tsk->tsk_active = 1;

        if (pthread_create(&tsk->tsk_pthr, NULL, &registration_atomic, tsk)
            != 0) {
            perror("There has been an error with pthread_create().");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // wait for all threads to complete
    int code = joinall();

    return code;
}

// patshow -- show patient data
void
patshow(void)
{
    const patient *pt;

    for (size_t ipat = 0; ipat < npatient; ipat++) {
        pt = &patients[ipat];
        if (pt->treatment == 'M' || pt->treatment == 'S') {
            printf("Treatment is: %c %zu\n", pt->treatment, ipat);
        }
    }
}

// tscgetf -- get hires timestamp
double
tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

// NOTE: this uses "designated initializers"
fnc_t fnclist[] = {
    { .fnc_ptr = perform_chunked, .fnc_who = "chunked" },
    { .fnc_ptr = perform_atomic, .fnc_who = "atomic" },
    { .fnc_ptr = NULL }
};

// dofnc -- benchmark a given method
double
dofnc(fnc_t *fnc,double tsclast)
{
    double tscbeg;
    double tscdif;
    double tscbest = 1e6;
    patient *pt;

    // do multiple trials and take the fastest (best) one
    for (int iter = 1;  iter <= 5;  ++iter) {
        // reset the random seed
        for (TSKFORALL(tsk))
            tsk->tsk_seed = seed;

        // reset records and heat up the cache
        for (size_t ipat = 0; ipat < npatient; ipat++) {
            pt = &patients[ipat];
            pt->treatment = 0;
        }

        tscbeg = tscgetf();
        fnc->fnc_ptr();
        tscdif = tscgetf();

        // get elapsed time
        tscdif -= tscbeg;

        // take the best time to account for system delays and timeslicing
        if (tscdif < tscbest)
            tscbest = tscdif;
    }

    printf("  ELAPSED=(%.9f) RATE=(%.3f p/s) -- %s",
        tscbest,(double) npatient / tscbest,fnc->fnc_who);

    do {
        if (tsclast == 0)
            break;

        printf(" --");

        double ratio;
        if (tsclast > tscbest) {
            ratio = tsclast / tscbest;
            printf(" %.3fx faster",ratio);
        }
        else {
            ratio = tscbest / tsclast;
            printf(" %.3fx slower",ratio);
        }
    } while (0);

    printf("\n");

    if ((fnc->fnc_nworker <= 0) || (tscbest < fnc->fnc_tscbest)) {
        fnc->fnc_nworker = nworker;
        fnc->fnc_tscbest = tscbest;
    }

    // remember this so we can take a ratio
    return tscbest;
}

void
dosize(int nwork,size_t npat)
{
    static int sep = 0;

    if (sep)
        printf("\n");
    sep = 1;

    if (nwork < 1)
        nwork = 1;
    if (nwork > NWORKER)
        nwork = NWORKER;
    nworker = nwork;

    if (npat < 1)
        npat = 1;
    if (npat > NPATIENT)
        npat = NPATIENT;
    npatient = npat;

    printf("NWORKER=%d NPATIENT=%d\n",nworker,npatient);

    double tscnow = 0;
    for (fnc_t *fnc = fnclist;  fnc->fnc_ptr != NULL;  ++fnc)
        tscnow = dofnc(fnc,tscnow);
}

int
main(void)
{

    seed = time(NULL);

    for (size_t nwork = 1;  nwork < 40;  ++nwork)
        dosize(nwork,1000);

    // show the best number of workers to use
    printf("\n");
    printf("best nworkers:\n");
    for (fnc_t *fnc = fnclist;  fnc->fnc_ptr != NULL;  ++fnc)
        printf("fnc_nworker=%d fnc_tscbest=%.9f -- %s\n",
            fnc->fnc_nworker,fnc->fnc_tscbest,fnc->fnc_who);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the program output. Look at the stats. The best number of workers to use is at the bottom. Surprises await!

```
NWORKER=1 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.032663233) RATE=(30615.463 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000046097) RATE=(21693397.459 p/s) -- atomic -- 708.576x faster

NWORKER=2 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.021753732) RATE=(45969.124 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000059036) RATE=(16938829.638 p/s) -- atomic -- 368.483x faster

NWORKER=3 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.021092976) RATE=(47409.147 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000083985) RATE=(11906898.974 p/s) -- atomic -- 251.152x faster

NWORKER=4 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.024977652) RATE=(40035.789 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000083009) RATE=(12046901.359 p/s) -- atomic -- 300.903x faster

NWORKER=5 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.038758768) RATE=(25800.614 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000139154) RATE=(7186281.370 p/s) -- atomic -- 278.531x faster

NWORKER=6 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.029736476) RATE=(33628.733 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000191748) RATE=(5215177.552 p/s) -- atomic -- 155.081x faster

NWORKER=7 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.026535172) RATE=(37685.831 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000234081) RATE=(4272024.389 p/s) -- atomic -- 113.359x faster

NWORKER=8 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.025485060) RATE=(39238.676 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000285933) RATE=(3497322.469 p/s) -- atomic -- 89.129x faster

NWORKER=9 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.026013032) RATE=(38442.270 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000263240) RATE=(3798813.732 p/s) -- atomic -- 98.819x faster

NWORKER=10 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.029725359) RATE=(33641.309 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000261056) RATE=(3830595.674 p/s) -- atomic -- 113.866x faster

NWORKER=11 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.026881332) RATE=(37200.538 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000271164) RATE=(3687805.203 p/s) -- atomic -- 99.133x faster

NWORKER=12 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.030074292) RATE=(33250.991 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000394198) RATE=(2536796.256 p/s) -- atomic -- 76.292x faster

NWORKER=13 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.030961288) RATE=(32298.398 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000345326) RATE=(2895815.125 p/s) -- atomic -- 89.658x faster

NWORKER=14 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.027436778) RATE=(36447.428 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000587254) RATE=(1702840.830 p/s) -- atomic -- 46.720x faster

NWORKER=15 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.032111215) RATE=(31141.768 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000391190) RATE=(2556302.194 p/s) -- atomic -- 82.086x faster

NWORKER=16 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.027765346) RATE=(36016.119 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000475762) RATE=(2101891.519 p/s) -- atomic -- 58.360x faster

NWORKER=17 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.026204446) RATE=(38161.463 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000951203) RATE=(1051300.372 p/s) -- atomic -- 27.549x faster

NWORKER=18 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.030340088) RATE=(32959.694 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000467318) RATE=(2139870.524 p/s) -- atomic -- 64.924x faster

NWORKER=19 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.028912229) RATE=(34587.440 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000553825) RATE=(1805624.340 p/s) -- atomic -- 52.205x faster

NWORKER=20 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.029094981) RATE=(34370.189 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000505824) RATE=(1976972.262 p/s) -- atomic -- 57.520x faster

NWORKER=21 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.031570002) RATE=(31675.639 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000901482) RATE=(1109284.549 p/s) -- atomic -- 35.020x faster

NWORKER=22 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.033848829) RATE=(29543.120 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000575106) RATE=(1738809.862 p/s) -- atomic -- 58.857x faster

NWORKER=23 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.029385494) RATE=(34030.396 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000793229) RATE=(1260669.853 p/s) -- atomic -- 37.045x faster

NWORKER=24 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.031210263) RATE=(32040.742 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000643074) RATE=(1555030.879 p/s) -- atomic -- 48.533x faster

NWORKER=25 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.029140703) RATE=(34316.262 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000715511) RATE=(1397602.482 p/s) -- atomic -- 40.727x faster

NWORKER=26 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.032022561) RATE=(31227.983 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000705709) RATE=(1417014.463 p/s) -- atomic -- 45.376x faster

NWORKER=27 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.029134086) RATE=(34324.056 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000724864) RATE=(1379569.210 p/s) -- atomic -- 40.192x faster

NWORKER=28 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.035466630) RATE=(28195.518 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000987683) RATE=(1012470.644 p/s) -- atomic -- 35.909x faster

NWORKER=29 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.035837240) RATE=(27903.935 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.001032722) RATE=(968314.850 p/s) -- atomic -- 34.702x faster

NWORKER=30 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.036233530) RATE=(27598.746 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.001048557) RATE=(953691.602 p/s) -- atomic -- 34.556x faster

NWORKER=31 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.034758216) RATE=(28770.176 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000810737) RATE=(1233445.583 p/s) -- atomic -- 42.872x faster

NWORKER=32 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.032050096) RATE=(31201.155 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.001110657) RATE=(900368.073 p/s) -- atomic -- 28.857x faster

NWORKER=33 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.028196867) RATE=(35464.933 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000948129) RATE=(1054708.812 p/s) -- atomic -- 29.739x faster

NWORKER=34 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.036432115) RATE=(27448.310 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000938635) RATE=(1065376.884 p/s) -- atomic -- 38.814x faster

NWORKER=35 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.029211664) RATE=(34232.901 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.001254896) RATE=(796878.827 p/s) -- atomic -- 23.278x faster

NWORKER=36 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.035125977) RATE=(28468.959 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.001015229) RATE=(984999.410 p/s) -- atomic -- 34.599x faster

NWORKER=37 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.027013535) RATE=(37018.480 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.000971639) RATE=(1029188.881 p/s) -- atomic -- 27.802x faster

NWORKER=38 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.027284315) RATE=(36651.094 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.001343600) RATE=(744269.135 p/s) -- atomic -- 20.307x faster

NWORKER=39 NPATIENT=1000
  ELAPSED=(0.026986172) RATE=(37056.015 p/s) -- chunked
  ELAPSED=(0.001386600) RATE=(721188.537 p/s) -- atomic -- 19.462x faster

best nworkers:
fnc_nworker=3 fnc_tscbest=0.021092976 -- chunked
fnc_nworker=1 fnc_tscbest=0.000046097 -- atomic
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are the best! Now it makes sense!

Comment: But why is it necessary to use pointer to struct in the below example you gave? And how can 2 thread race for 0 or 1 when I only loop for once (create only 1 thread)?

Comment: Thank you so much again. Can you please expend the names of `patlo`, `pathi`, `ipat` and `itsk`? And yes, what I want was working with 1000 threads at once, but as you said above it is problematic and I have 4 CPU only. Is it a better idea to change `NWORKER` to 4?

Comment: Can this be done by semaphores or mutex_locks? Let's say I can only let 10 thread inside of my registration function.

Comment: I can't thank you enough sir. You are a good man, thank you so much!